# Htaccess Redirect being Ignored

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a strange problem where google is indexing an unstyled version of my homepage.  The URI that results in this problem is my "root host"/index.php/"subpage".  So for example www.website.com/index.php/photos would cause this problem.

To rectify this I've created the following Htaccess directive to redirect any permutation of this URL to the homepage:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

Redirect 301 /index.php^(.*)$ /
```

The redirect works, however for some reason the first section causes that redirect to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect directive does not support regex. What you are looking for is **RedirectMatch** .

```
RedirectMatch ^/index\.php/(.*)$ /
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  That's not the issue though, the redirect is still being ignored.  I tested the rule on its own and it worked.  For some reason though the previous block nullifies it.